# Check Nginx captured variable

Tags: nginx

I have Nginx rule:

```
location ~ ^/a/(.*) {
  return 301 /b/$1;
}
```

So when url is `http://example.com/a/something`, it returns `http://example.com/b/something`.

And if url is `http://example.com/a/`, it returns `http://example.com/b/`. But I need `http://example.com/a/` if `$1` is undefined.

I unsuccessfully tried to use `if`:

```
location ~ ^/a/(.*) {
  if ($1) {
    return 301 /b/$1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was so easy:

```
location ~ ^/a/(.+) {
  return 301 /b/$1;
}
```